# Facing error while using "Remote" and "Compare" annotation at a time

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I am using Remote validation to validate if username is already taken or not, its working fine. But now I need to add 'compare' data annotation to compare `password` and `confirmPassword` fields. But Its giving me error for missing assembly. When I remove Library `System.Web.Mvc` (which is used for `Remote`), then error goes away.
Is there any conflict between `remote` and `compare` or I'm missing something.

```
using System.Web.Mvc
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotaion

public partial class user
{
    [Remote("CheckExistingUsername","Home",ErrorMessage = "Email already exists!")]
    public string Username{get;set;}
    public string password {get;set;}

    [Compare("password",ErrorMessage="Un Matched")]
    public string confirmPassword {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Your question need to include the code, not an image of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to add compare with namespace

```
[System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Compare("pass",ErrorMessage = "unmatched")]
```

by default it is using the compare of  `System.Web.Mvc.CompareAttribute` which might be causing problem

Answer (score 0):

Do like this,

```
[CompareAttribute("pass", ErrorMessage = "Unmatched")]
```

For more info regarding **CompareAttribute** click [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.compareattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)